# Balance between improving the system and generating revenue

Tags: management, project-management, startup, task-management, micro-management

I'm an online marketer, I'm doing two kind of tasks

1 - tasks that actually generate money

2 - tasks for improving my system, by developing tools, automation...

My problem is sometimes I focus too much on improving the systems tasks which consume time and money, which causes less cashflow for the business...

Any ideas on how to find balance between development and making money ?

Answer (score 9):

The simple answer is to focus on the money generation until the workflow becomes a limiter.  Then fix the workflow.  Workflow doesn't matter if there is no money coming in.  It also doesn't matter as long as it's not impacting your ability to generate cash.  Keep repeating that to yourself until it finally sinks in.

Comment: I agree, prioritise the cash generation, it pays for the rest.

Comment: Besides, if the cash is coming in, you can pay someone else to improve the systems. Focus on the cash.

Answer (score 6):

There's something called "Sharpening the axe".

It goes all the way back to the days of lumberjacks.  If they didn't take time to stop and sharpen the axe, they would actually be able to chop less wood than if they had taken the time.

## 2 is your "Sharpening the axe"

If your systems, tools, and automation are not working well, #1 isn't going to be what it should.

As to how you should strike the balance, it's a simple matter of when not doing 2 becomes painful.  When you realize that you are not getting as much done as you should.  Revenue isn't growing, et cet.

Comment: +1 because it makes sense and is a factor, I call that more maintenance though, not tweaking so much. More a normal part of the cash generating workflow. We'd sit around sharpening and oiling for pretty set periods. Mostly chainsaws though... I'm pretty old... but not a dinosaur :-)